# How to scroll lock background image of a div in react

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

The content in DesktopView.js has vertical scroll. I want the make the backgound static. Basically when I scroll down I want the content to scroll down but the background img should should not.

I tried a a few approaches after looking around online but none seems to work.

My code is below. Do tell if morw info is needed.

**DesktopView.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import Header from './components/Header'
import Navbar from './components/Navbar'
import Content from './components/Content';

export default function DesktopView() {
  
  const [content, setContent] = React.useState();

  return (
    <div className='desktopView'>
        <Header/>
        <Navbar
          content={content}
          setContent={setContent}
        />
        <Content
          content={content}
          setContent={setContent}
        />
    </div>
  )
}
```

**App.css**

```
.desktopView {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    background-image: url('./assets/bg.png');
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your css stylesheet, try doing this:

```
body {
    background-image: url('./assets/bg.png');
    /* ... */
}
```

This will add the background directly to the body.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if understand well, but why dont try to you content put an overflow so that you backgroundo will be in the same place  but the content will scroll down

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by setting height property to the content as well